# python: need to iterate and create a single value in dataframe based on date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns `[Company', 'Date', 'Headline', 'Page', 'Subtext', 'Time','Year', 'Sentiment analysis']`.

I am trying to do the sentiment analysis based on date for the company based on news. I want to calculate score for all the news for a company for each day. How to do it .

The date and Company columns are repeating [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM6bD.png)

How to do it ?

Comment: Lets say on a given day , I have more than one news item. I want to collate all the news for that day and calculate the score. How to do it ?

Comment: Hi vishwa and welcome to SO! When posting questions it is best to post your input as text format, a sample of the code you have tried that can reproduce the problem, and your expected output. This helps people answer your question much more easily!